# CsvHelper not writing anything to memory stream

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have the following method:

```
public byte[] WriteCsvWithHeaderToMemory<T>(IEnumerable<T> records) where T : class
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
    {
        csvWriter.WriteRecords<T>(records);

        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Which is being called with a list of objects - eventually from a database, but since something is not working I'm just populating a static collection.  The objects being passed are as follows:

```
using CsvHelper.Configuration;

namespace Application.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class Model
    {
        [CsvField(Name = "Field 1", Ignore = false)]
        public string Field1 { get; set; }

        [CsvField(Name = "Statistic 1", Ignore = false)]
        public int Stat1{ get; set; }

        [CsvField(Name = "Statistic 2", Ignore = false)]
        public int Stat2{ get; set; }

        [CsvField(Name = "Statistic 3", Ignore = false)]
        public int Stat3{ get; set; }

        [CsvField(Name = "Statistic 4", Ignore = false)]
        public int Stat4{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is write a collection to a csv for download in an MVC application.  Every time I try to write to the method though, the MemoryStream is coming back with zero length and nothing being passed to it.  I've used this before, but for some reason it's just not working - I'm somewhat confused.  Can anyone point out to me what I've done wrong here?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried flushing your stream? put `csvWriter.Flush();` before you return.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it would be something daft, but I've lost half my morning staring at it unable to think of what was wrong...

Comment: That worked? great.  Would you like me to submit it as an answer for future searchers or will you submit the solution yourself?

Comment: If you could submit one and I'll check it answer so you get the credit.

Comment: CsvField Attribute is not supported now, instead you can use [CsvClassMap](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) and then register them as: csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new MyClassMap);

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Put `csvWriter.Flush();` before you return to flush the writer/stream.

EDIT: Per Jack's response.  It should be the stream that gets flushed, not the csvWriter. `streamWriter.Flush();`.  Leaving original solution, but adding this correction.

EDIT 2: My preferred answer is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22997765/1795053 Let the using statements do the heavy lifting for you

Comment: This is a wrong answer. There is no Flush method on CsvWriter.

Comment: My preferred answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22997765/1795053 Let the `using` statements do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: streamwriter.Flush(); worked for me. Thanks for your help. Also Thanks to @JackHughes

Comment: There is a `Flush` on CsvHelper >= 17, which was the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 83):

You already have a `using` block which is great. That will flush your writer for you. You can just change your code slightly for it to work.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
    {
        csvWriter.WriteRecords<T>(records);
    } // StreamWriter gets flushed here.

    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

If you turn `AutoFlush` on, you need to be careful. This will flush after every write. If your stream is a network stream and over the wire, it will be very slow.

Comment: I think this is incorrect. If you do this, the StreamWriter will get flushed but it will also dispose of the underlying stream.

Comment: Yes, the return should be inside the using block.

Comment: Seems like CsvWriter has two bugs in version 3.0.0.0. It does not flush on Dispose. This is one thing and the second is that first record is not separated by new line from the header. 
So flushing csvWriter is a necessary workaround.

Comment: Please submit a bug on GitHub and I'll fix ASAP

Comment: @RadekStrugalski Fixed the first issue. The second you need to call `NextRecord()` manually now. This is to give more control to the user. You can write a header and do some more manual writing this way.

Comment: Thank you it is not time saving but it is awesome than anything else

Answer (score 33):

Putting all these together (and the comments for corrections), including resetting the memory stream position, the final solution for me was;

```
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms))
            using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(tw, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csv.WriteRecords(errors); // Converts error records to CSV

                tw.Flush(); // flush the buffered text to stream
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // reset stream position

                Attachment a = new Attachment(ms, "errors.csv"); // Create attachment from the stream
                // I sent an email here with the csv attached.
            }
        }
```

In case the helps someone else!

Comment: `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` was the missing piece for me. Flushes, using statements, none of it made a difference until I reset the stream.

Comment: Answer not working and is possible outdated.   CsvWriter(tw) no longer accepts only one argument, even when added it still throws an error complaining about closed memory stream.

Answer (score 9):

There is no flush in csvWriter, the flush is in the streamWriter. When called

> csvWriter.Dispose();

it will flush the stream.
Another approach is to set

> streamWriter.AutoFlush = true;

which will automatically flush the stream every time.

Answer (score 8):

Here is working example:

```
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<dynamic>{
       new { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
       new { Id = 2, Name = "two" },
    };

    Console.WriteLine(records.ToCsv());
}

public static class Extensions {
    public static string ToCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
            {
                csvWriter.WriteRecords(collection);
            } // StreamWriter gets flushed here.

            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22997765/147613) answer.

Answer (score 0):

```html
using CsvHelper;
public class TwentyFoursStock
{
    [Name("sellerSku")]
    public string ProductSellerSku { get; set; }

    [Name("shippingPoint")]
    public string ProductShippingPoint { get; set; }
}

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(TwentyFoursStock);
}
```

Comment: This works fne with me, the Name attributes where you can specific headers coloums name

Comment: `csv.WriteRecords(TwentyFoursStock);` accepts collections only?
`TwentyFoursStock` - should it be a collection?